# Unique with sort ignores 2nd condition

Tags: excel-formula

I am using the following formula to create a unique list with 2 conditions, the formula works fine:
`=UNIQUE(FILTER('Credit Pulls'!$E$2:$E$150000,('Credit Pulls'!$D$2:$D$150000=Summary!M17)*('Credit Pulls'!$AI$2:$AI$150000 >0)))`

However, I also ant to sort the list, but when I add the sort part to the formula it ignores my second criteria
`=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER('Credit Pulls'!$E$2:$E$150000,('Credit Pulls'!$D$2:$D$150000=Summary!M17)*('Credit Pulls'!$AI$2:$AI$150000 >0))))`

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Column AI has a 0 or 1, I do not want to include any results that have a 0

Comment: Without seeing sample data it is hard to judge.

Comment: There's no reason why it should do that and I am unable to replicate your issue using the same set up (doube condition for filter, with outer unique and sort functions).  Are you sure you're not dragging the function across -thereby displacing M17? try and fix ($M$17).  if you could provide sample data using scaled down example that you can include a screenshot of in your Q - you'd probably discover the error yourself in doing so. The only other thing  I can think of is if there was an error #value! somewhere that th unique didn't like - including iferror() somewere within might help.  What..

Comment: ...happens if you change the order of the sort and unique (i.e. have `=unique(sort(filter..)))` ?

Answer (score 0):

This requires troubleshooting to discover where the error ariss --

a) Create the unique(filter(..)) list in a column within excel, then apply (to that spill # range) the sort function - do the two columns have different lengths? If not - there is no issue (it would seem)

b) Are there any cells within the filter range, or filter criteria range that dependent (or link to) the results of the unique(sort()) output (if so , do you have iterative calculation on?)

c) Scale down by using, say,the first 10-20 rows, and see if you encounter same issue (I doubt you will)

d) Then extend range to 75k rows (half of desired) - do you still encounter issue? if so, cut back the range to 37.5k rows? if no issue then try half way between 37.5 and 75 - effectively honing in where exactly the problem arises.

e) Do you have any blank cells, or #value! values in any of the cells (target filter range, the set of two conditions?

f) If you swap around the two conditions within the filter - i.e. (D:D * AI:AI) -> (AI:AI * D:D), what do you find (does it now 'ignore' the 'new' 2nd condition (D:D) or does it figure out what you've done and now ignore the new first? (AI:AI) ☺

g) Do all above but chanage the order in which you sort - you could sort i) before filter ii) after filter but before unique - do you still encounter issues under a-f) above?

As noted - I was unable to replicate your error myself with pseudo/scaled down example - per screenshot - so I gather there must be something you're overlooking that you would probably uncover once you started attempting above troubleshooting suggestions.

[image: Troubleshooting examples - shows no concerns+ conlusion]

Answer (score 0):

After going through some of the testing that was recommended I discovered it was a something so easy to fix, I was typing in the criteria I needed and it did not work. It was more of a user error than the formula. I learned a lot from this experience, thank you for all that helped.